# Postfix: Is it possible to rebuild mail queue to fix incorrectly generated addresses?

Tags: postfix

I am new to postfix and I was playing with the config file, with $mydomains and other variables. During this time I had some mails in the queue, and they now have incorrect to addresses showing in postfix queue like
mydomain@com.com

When I look inside the mail body fortunately the To address is correct.

Is it possible to rebuild the mail qiueue now that I corrected the postfix config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding a fake "com.com" virtual domain, and created an email catch all rule for the original address, and then I requeued the mails.
Arrgh

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue. Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.